# Nav bar using slidetoggle

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, nav

I have a Nav bar with a Login and Sign up. When i click on the a(also called the Trigger) the slide up and down but i dont hide the other "tab"

If i click the A("#login-trigger) i would like it to hide my Signup page if. and the other way around ofc with the signup-trigger.

i would be so happy if someone could help me since i have been trying for a few hours now, including trying some codes from here.

This is my entire Jquery script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#login-trigger').click(function () {
        $(this).next('#login-content').slideToggle();
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) $(this).find('span').html('&#x25B2;')
        else $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;');
    })
    $('#signup-trigger').click(function () {
        $(this).next('#signup-content').slideToggle();
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) $(this).find('span').html('&#x25B2;')
        else $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;');
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Creating a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) may help us understand your problem more.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8A4T7/ here it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you wanting something like this?
This toggles the clicked item but slides up the alternate.

http://jsfiddle.net/8A4T7/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#login-trigger').click(function () {
        $('#login-content').slideToggle();
        $('#signup-content').slideUp();
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) $(this).find('span').html('&#x25B2;')
        else $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;');
    })
    $('#signup-trigger').click(function () {
        $('#login-content').slideUp();
        $('#signup-content').slideToggle();
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) $(this).find('span').html('&#x25B2;')
        else $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;');
    });
});
```

Comment: That you my friend you are my hero:D i would up vote you if i could. thanks